# convert Bytes to string rust

Tags: rust

I am using this code to parse the http response, the server will return a json string, this is the rust code:

```
use reqwest::Client;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let client = Client::new();
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
    let response = client.get(url).send().await;
    if response.is_ok() {
        let wrap_response = response.expect("msg");
        let resp_bytes = wrap_response.bytes().await;
        let json_str = std::str::from_utf8(resp_bytes.unwrap()).unwrap();
        println!("{}", "wrap_response");
    } else {
        println!("Error: {}", response.unwrap_err());
    }
}
```

this line `let json_str = std::str::from_utf8(resp_bytes.unwrap()).unwrap();` shows that expected `&[u8]`, found `Bytes`. is it possible to convert Bytes to string? this is my cargo config:

```
[package]
name = "rust-learn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
num-bigint = "0.2.1"
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["json"] }
tokio = { version = "1.17.0", features = ["full"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
```

the response from server may look like this:

```
{
   "result":{
      "id":4,
      "name":"template",
      "remark":"template",
      "created_time":0,
      "updated_time":0,
      "template_status":0,
      "template_id":1,
      "preview_url":"1",
      "template_code":null
   },
   "statusCode":"200",
   "resultCode":"200",
   "msg":"ok"
}
```

the result/statusCode/resultCode/msg are immutable, the result data are dynamic.

Comment: it *feels like* you aren't setting up the response from `reqwest` properly.  Why are you explicitly reading bytes if what you really want is the json?  It would be much easier to provide assistance if you can post what the response from the server looks like.

Comment: You can get from `Bytes` to `&[u8]` by calling `as_ref` or `deref` or `borrow`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Bytes` implements `Deref<Target = [u8]>`, you can get `&[u8]` by taking a reference.

```rs
std::str::from_utf8(&resp_bytes.unwrap())
```

However, this is redundant with reqwest's built-in JSON support.

```rs
if response.is_ok() {
    let wrap_response = response.expect("msg");
    let json: serde_json::Value = wrap_response.json().await.expect("Response was not json");
    println!("{:?}", json);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to convert Bytes to string? this is my cargo config:

`from_utf8` is what converts bytes to string, the problem is converting Bytes to bytes. `Bytes` deref' to `&[u8]`, so you just have to `&` it: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=83c784cd012b5e7db03bf1cf06763464

```rust
        let json_str = std::str::from_utf8(&resp_bytes.unwrap()).unwrap();
```

Although that is a lot more complicated than necessary, `reqwest::Response` has both [`text()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.text) and [`json()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.json) helpers, so you can just use that directly if you don't need raw bytes...

You can also simplify a lot of the error handling:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let client = Client::new();
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
    let response = client.get(url).send().await;
    match response {
        Ok(r) => {
            // the return type of json() would normally be inferred
            // but I obviously don't have the schema so a generic 
            // value works well enough for now
            let r: serde_json::Value = r.json().await?;
            println!("{:?}", r);
        }
        Err(e) => println!("Error: {}", e)
    }
    Ok(())
}
```